# Texture Coordinates not working correctly in OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: c, opengl-es-2.0

I am trying to apply part of a big image to a rectangle in OpenGL ES 2.0

I have this big texture sheet or sprite sheet. Each image is 32x32. The Full Image is 192x32.
[image]

Loading the Texture

```c
glGenTextures(1, &texture->textureId);
bindTexture(texture);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

stbi_set_flip_vertically_on_load(true);

unsigned char* textureData = stbi_load(texturePath, &texture->width, &texture->height, &texture->channels, 0);
if(textureData)
{
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, texture->width, texture->height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, textureData);
}
else
{
    log_error("Couldn't load texture: %s", texturePath);
}

stbi_image_free(textureData);
```

So, To get the first sprite from this sprite sheet, I use ((1*32)/192) and get these texture coordinates
[image]

```c
static Vertex vertices[4] =
{
//  Position               Color                          Tex Coords
    {{{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}}, {{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}}, {{0.16f, 1.0f}}},
    {{{1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f}}, {{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}}, {{0.16, 0.0f}}},
    {{{-1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f}}, {{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}}, {{0.0f, 0.0f}}},
    {{{-1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f}}, {{1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}}, {{0.0f, 1.0f}}},
};
```

Fragment Shader

```c
#version 100

precision mediump float;

varying vec4 fColor;
varying vec2 fTexCoord;

uniform sampler2D textureSampler;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(textureSampler, fTexCoord);
}
```

But I don't get the expected output. Instead it applies the full sprite sheet onto the rectangle
[image]

Why is this happening?
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The texture coordinates of your vertices seem to be off. Since each sprite is 32 pixels in height and the whole image is 32 pixels in height too, you would use 1.0 for the height. I guess your x component of the texture coordinates seem to be right tho.

I had a similar approach on a little game and the vertices look like this:

```
    float width = 1.0f / (float)m_spriteCount;
    float widthMin = m_spritePos * width;
    float widthMax = (m_spritePos + 1) * width;

    m_vertices = {
        //                x,                   y,          z,       w,    h
        size.x + position.x, size.y + position.y, position.z, widthMax, 1.0f,       // top right
        size.x + position.x,          position.y, position.z, widthMax, 0.0f,       // bottom right
                 position.x,          position.y, position.z, widthMin, 0.0f,       // bottom left
                 position.x, size.y + position.y, position.z, widthMin, 1.0f        // top left
    };
```

`m_spriteCount` is the count of images I have in my texture (in your case 6) and `m_spritePos` is the current texture position I am rendering (from 0 - 5).

I dont use any data for a color since the texture already contains the color (obviously) and I dont want to mix some colors but only render the textures colores.

Comment: I changed the 0.16 to 1.0 in y component of texture coordinate. But I still get the same result

Comment: @Techie-Guy Do you maybe change the texture position in the shaders? And how do you update the position for each frame? I think the rest of your posted code looks right.

Comment: No, I don't change the texture coordinates in the fragment shader. But, I have edited the question and added the fragment shader. I am not updating/changing the texture coordinates for now, It's all hardcoded as I am figuring it out.

Comment: @Techie-Guy I am using OpenGL with glfw3 and my code therefore looks a bit different but the only thing I could think of right now which might cause some incorrect results would be the process of copying the vertices data to the GPU with a VertexArray/VertexBuffer but I dont know how you would do this with OpenGL-ES. Since you have some colors stored in your vertices you might be using them for the position instead?

Comment: I have a VBO(`GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`) and a EBO(`GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER`). OpenGL ES 2 does not support VAOs.

Comment: As for the color data, it is working correctly, as when I set `gl_FragColor` to `fColor`, the given color is rendered